# Permutation and Combination of words

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Follow up of [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237619/generate-permutations-and-combination-for-name-column/237636?noredirect=1#comment468588_237636)

I have the following data:

I have the following sample data for permutations and combination.

```
create table tbltest
(
    name varchar(50),
    addres varchar(100)
);

insert into tbltest values('Sam Mak John','Street 1 HNo 101 USA');
insert into tbltest values('Donatella Nobatti','HNo 101 UK');
insert into tbltest values('Sam Buca','Main Road B Block UAE');
insert into tbltest values('Juan Soponatime','Hight Street CA');
insert into tbltest values('Aaron Spacemuseum','HNo A10 100 feet Road A Block ');
insert into tbltest values('Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy','UAE High Street');
```

For an example expected result:

```
name
----------------
John Mak Sam
John Sam Mak
Mak John Sam
Mak Sam John
Sam John Mak
Sam Mak John
....
....
```

Tried the solution from previous question:

```
--To store Words 
CREATE TABLE dbo.NameParts
(
  ID int NOT NULL,
  NamePart varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

--Table variable to identity column for each words
DECLARE @Inter TABLE (id int identity(1,1), names varchar(max));

--Insert into table variable
INSERT INTO @Inter(names) SELECT name from TblTest;

--Query to insert into NameParts table
;WITH splitdata 
AS 
(
    SELECT id,splitname 
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT *,Cast('<X>' + Replace(F.Names, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS  xmlfilter 
        FROM   @Inter F
    )F1 
    CROSS apply 
    (
        SELECT fdata.d.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS splitName 
        FROM   f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(d)
    ) O
) 
INSERT INTO dbo.NameParts
SELECT * 
FROM splitdata;
```

Query for Permutation and Combination:

```
--Query for Permutation and Combination
;WITH
  permutations AS
  (
    SELECT
      ID = t.ID,
      FullNameVariation = CAST(t.NamePart AS varchar(500)),
      Level = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
    FROM
      dbo.NameParts AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      ID = t.ID,
      FullNameVariation = CAST(p.FullNameVariation + ' ' + t.NamePart AS varchar(500)),
      Level = p.Level - 1
    FROM
      dbo.NameParts AS t
      INNER JOIN permutations AS p ON t.ID = p.ID
    WHERE 1=1
      AND p.Level > 1
      AND ' ' + p.FullNameVariation + ' ' NOT LIKE '% ' + t.NamePart + ' %'
  )
SELECT
  ID,
  FullNameVariation
FROM
  permutations
WHERE
  Level = 1
ORDER BY
  ID,
  FullNameVariation 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5100);
```

**Note**: Above query works fine but unable to get following record in the result set:

`Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy`

and that is because of this condition:

```
' ' + p.FullNameVariation + ' ' NOT LIKE '% ' + t.NamePart + ' %'
```

The word `Ahmed` is repeated and the above condition not met.

Comment: Check my script, Can you give example of `'Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy'` What is Combination of this ?

Comment: check my answer. Can you give output of repeated words like `Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending the [original answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237636/44945) by [Andriy M](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m) we can *uniqify* the strings at the insert phase with a dummy character (in my case I used ~), and remove that character later.

In this case I chose to use REPLICATE passing in the dummy character '~' and the ROW_NUMBER function for the number of instances to replicate. This should ensure that all strings are unique.

[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d955dd183c7a057968f57c0f35fdad3a)

Full code

```
create table tbltest
(
    name varchar(50),
    addres varchar(100)
);

insert into tbltest values('Sam Mak John','Street 1 HNo 101 USA');
insert into tbltest values('Donatella Nobatti','HNo 101 UK');
insert into tbltest values('Sam Buca','Main Road B Block UAE');
insert into tbltest values('Juan Soponatime','Hight Street CA');
insert into tbltest values('Aaron Spacemuseum','HNo A10 100 feet Road A Block ');
insert into tbltest values('Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy','UAE High Street');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.NameParts
(
  ID int NOT NULL,
  NamePart varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

--Table variable to identity column for each words
DECLARE @Inter TABLE (id int identity(1,1), names varchar(max));

--Insert into table variable
INSERT INTO @Inter(names) SELECT name from TblTest;

--Query to insert into NameParts table
;WITH splitdata 
AS 
(
    SELECT id,splitname 
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT *,Cast('<X>' + Replace(F.Names, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS  xmlfilter 
        FROM   @Inter F
    )F1 
    CROSS apply 
    (
        SELECT fdata.d.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS splitName 
        FROM   f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(d)
    ) O
) 
INSERT INTO dbo.NameParts
SELECT id,[splitdata].[splitName] + REPLICATE('~',(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [splitdata].[id] ORDER BY [splitdata].[splitName] ASC))
FROM splitdata;
GO

;WITH
  permutations AS
  (
    SELECT
      ID = t.ID,
      FullNameVariation = CAST(t.NamePart AS varchar(500)),
      Level = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
    FROM
      dbo.NameParts AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      ID = t.ID,
      FullNameVariation = CAST(p.FullNameVariation + ' ' + t.NamePart AS varchar(500)),
      Level = p.Level - 1
    FROM
      dbo.NameParts AS t
      INNER JOIN permutations AS p ON t.ID = p.ID
    WHERE 1=1
      AND p.Level > 1
      AND ' ' + p.FullNameVariation + ' ' NOT LIKE '% ' + t.NamePart + ' %'
  )
SELECT
  ID,
  REPLACE(FullNameVariation,'~','')
FROM
  permutations
WHERE 1=1 AND
  Level = 1
ORDER BY
  ID,
  FullNameVariation 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5100);

DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbltest]
DROP TABLE [dbo].[NameParts]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention number of rows return in output if `Ahmed` is repeated.

In my script, `74 rows` are return. It count `Ahmed` as one.

If different `Output` is desire then show the `Example` of repeated word like `'Ahmed'`

Any Split string function that also return row number.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit2K]

        (@pString VARCHAR(2000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (

                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )

 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Number Table,

```
create table tblnumber(number int not null)
insert into tblnumber (number)
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a.number) from master..spt_values a
, master..spt_values b
CREATE unique clustered index CI_num on tblnumber(number)
```

Sample Data,

```
create table #tbltest
(
    id int  identity(1,1),
    name varchar(50),
    addres varchar(100)
);

insert into #tbltest values('Sam Mak John','Street 1 HNo 101 USA');
insert into #tbltest values('Donatella Nobatti','HNo 101 UK');
insert into #tbltest values('Sam Buca','Main Road B Block UAE');
insert into #tbltest values('Juan Soponatime','Hight Street CA');
insert into #tbltest values('Aaron Spacemuseum','HNo A10 100 feet Road A Block ');
insert into #tbltest values('Nasir Ahmed Amir Ahmed Mehendy','UAE High Street');
```

The Scripts (WITHOUT RBAR),

```
create table #tbltest1
(
    id int  identity(1,1),
    name varchar(50)
    ,GroupID int
    ,rownum int

);
insert into #tbltest1 (name,GroupID,rownum)
select item,t.id, ca.ItemNumber from #tbltest t
cross apply(select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit2K(t.name,' '))ca


DECLARE 
    @max integer = 
    POWER(
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM #tbltest1 AS s
        )
        ,3
    ) ;


;With CTE as
(
SELECT s.id
        ,s.GroupID
        ,ltrim((select ' '+name from #tbltest1 t1  where t1.GroupID =s.groupid order by (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(c.n)) for xml PATH('') ))name
    FROM #tbltest1 AS s
CROSS APPLY (
select top (@max) number n FROM dbo.tblnumber 
)c

)   

select distinct name from CTE
--where groupid=1 


drop table #tbltest
drop table #tbltest1
```

How many rows will be process at one time ?

How many rows are there is table ?

Above all how many average word can be there in column `Name`