# Sum of decimal values that come in a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, substring, string-splitting

Is there an easy way to get the sum of all decimal values in a string column.

Example:

```
"ABC $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ2 $0.25"
"ABC1 $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ $0.25, KLM $4.50"
```

I want to add only the values after the `$` and before a `,`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL version is 2016 or later, you could try to use STRING_SPLIT function.
Against earlier version, there are also lots of impletmentations of string split by searching GG.

Below is my example for SQL 2016+:

```
DECLARE @v nvarchar(256) = N'ABC $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ2 $0.25,ABC1 $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ $0.25, KLM $4.50'
SELECT  TRIM(value), RIGHT(value, LEN(value)-CHARINDEX('$',value))
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@v,',')
SELECT  SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2),RIGHT(value, LEN(value)-CHARINDEX('$',value))))
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@v,',')
```

Answer (score 1):

The below example should work in SQL 2012. It assumes your string will always feature 3 alphabetical characters, a space, a dollar sign and a comma separating individual values. If this is not the case, you will either need to data cleanse or amend the script to handle the different scenarios.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABC $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ $0.25, KLM $15.75, NOP $.75'

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 0 a, 1 b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b, CAST(CHARINDEX(',', @str, b) + LEN(',') AS INT)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE b > a
)

SELECT LEFT(value, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', value)+2) Code, REPLACE(value, LEFT(value, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', value)+2), '') AS Amount
FROM 
(
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str, a,
    CASE 
        WHEN b > LEN(',') THEN b - a - LEN(',') 
        ELSE LEN(@str) - a + 1 
    END), ' ', ''), '$', '') AS value       
    FROM cte 
    WHERE a > 0
) src
```

Results:

```
Code    Amount
--------------
ABC     3.25
DEF     2.50
HIJ     0.25
KLM     15.75
NOP     .75
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need  Split String function ,[DelimitedSplit2K](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237720/permutation-and-combination-of-words/238213#238213)

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t VALUES
('ABC $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ2 $0.25')
,('ABC1 $3.25, DEF $2.50, HIJ $0.25, KLM $4.50');

With CTE1 as
 (
select col1,item
,stuff(item,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',item)-1,'') aa
from @t
CROSS APPLY(select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit2K(col1,','))ca
)
,CTE AS(
select col1,item,SUBSTRING(item,CHARINDEX('$',item)+1,len(item))bb

from cte1
)
select col1,
sum(cast(bb as decimal(5,2)))  
from cte
--where ISNUMERIC(aa)=1
group by col1
```